# igraph - distances between communities

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, distance, igraph

How can we calculate the distances between communities in the same graph? I want to measure how far away communities are from each other -applying igraph package.
Kind regards.

My intention would be to create an indicator of the average (nearest) distance from each of the nodes in community 1 to all points in community 2. I don't know if this is an outrage, I am not an expert in networks. My intention is to assess how far away or close the thematic communities are (bibliometric analysis). –

Comment: When there are multiple nodes involved, there is not a single definition of distance. Do you want the distance between the nearest nodes?  The furthest nodes? How are you defining the distance between two communities?

Comment: @majesus Can you please post a sample of your data? The sample can be artificially created, of course. Thank you!